# Website does not work on my iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, mobile

As the title says, my website won't work on my iPhone. (fredriksande.no)
My errorlog said that it can't find `public.html/fredriksande.no/mobile`. I deleted the `htaccess` content from a weebly page but it did not fix the problem. I'm new to HTML, but I will add my HTML code. I tried making a `/mobile` folder and adding `index.html`, but that did not work. Why is it looking for the /mobile folder? Content are supposed to to be responsive..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="#">
```

File Structure:

```
/public_html
    /fredriksande.no
        /1-Documentation
        /components
        /css
        /img
        /js
        /less
        /.ftpquota
        /.htaccess
        /error_log
        /index.html
        /mailer.php
```

Comment: Please provide your file structure.

Comment: /public_html/fredriksande.no/1-Documentation
/public_html/fredriksande.no/components
/public_html/fredriksande.no/css
/public_html/fredriksande.no/img
/public_html/fredriksande.no/js
/public_html/fredriksande.no/less
/public_html/fredriksande.no/.ftpquota
/public_html/fredriksande.no/.htaccess
/public_html/fredriksande.no/error_log
/public_html/fredriksande.no/index.html
/public_html/fredriksande.no/mailer.php

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a direct answer, but why not use [CSS media rules](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to create a responsive site, rather than having a dedicated mobile version?

Comment: I thought the @media code made it responsive. It is supposed to be responsive, but somehow it is still looking for the /mobile version. 

copy-right p a{color:#fff}.my-socmed ul.my-social{margin:0;text-align:right}@media (min-width:240px) and (max-width:767px){.copy-right p{text-align:center}.my-socmed ul.my-social{text-align:center}}